# Delete All records in a Siebel List View

Tags: siebel

I need to Delete All the records in a list applet by a button clicked method. In order to achieve this, I have added a button to the list applet with "DeleteAllRecords" method and added a script to BC PreInvokeMethod function as below. Once clicked on the button all the records will get deleted, but the applet won't get refreshed. How Can I achieve that?

```
try
    {
    if(MethodName == "DeleteAllRecords")
    {
                var EmpBO = TheApplication().GetBusObject("XXXX");
                var EmpBC = EmpBO.GetBusComp("XXXX");
                
                with(EmpBC)
                {
                    SetViewMode(AllView);
                    ActivateField("EmployeeID");
                    ClearToQuery();
                    SetSearchExpr("[XXXX] <> ' '");
                    ExecuteQuery(ForwardOnly);
        
                    var Frecord = FirstRecord();
    
                    while(Frecord)
                    {   
                        Frecord = DeleteRecord();
                        Frecord = FirstRecord();
                    }
                }
                //BC.InvokeMethod("RefreshBuscomp");
                return (CancelOperation);

    }
    }       
    catch(e)
    {
        throw(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        EmpBO = null;
        EmpBC = null;
    }

    return (ContinueOperation);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a few things.
1: A simple null query in the end after all deletions are done. ClearToQuery() and ExecuteQuery();
2: There is a BC method for RefreshBusComp (check documentation) which can be used with InvokeMethod(). Does pretty much the same thing as 1. I see you already tried it and probably did not work.

3: There are Business services which can refresh applets , like FINS Teller UI navigation.

4: You could also try a null query in browserscript/javascript, put that in InvokeMethod, so that it runs after the BC escript. Genb has to be run to generate bscripts.

One of these should work .

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Tried the first method and it worked fine!!!

Comment: Do you know a proper way to add an alert message before deleting the records? RaiseErrorText want work since it stops executing the rest of the script.

Comment: Recommend browser script alert messages, which provides Ok and Cancel buttons. The script can be added to applet preinvoke browserscript.